# How can I create an ER diagram for a database from the data alone without using a tool?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-relationship

I have an sql database with 35 tables in it and I have to create an ER diagram mapping the relationship between the tables. Each table has an identifying key value (hmy). I have been looking for tables which have keys that point to another table. For example one table may have a key called hinspection, and then there is a table called inspections which this is related to. I then execute a join statement:

```
select hinspection.hmy, hothertable.hinspection, hothertable.hmy from hinspection
inner join hothertable on hinspection.hmy=hothertable.hinspection
```

and then can see how many of each instance of one table map to how many of each instance of the other table (ex: there are three different othertable hmy records for every instance of an hinspection hmy record). This helps me create some of the one to many or one to one relationships, but I know that there are relationships that cannot be determined in this way. What other ways can I use to figure out the relationships WITHOUT USING A TOOL.

edit: I am using microsoft sql server management studio 2008

Comment: *Without a tool* you can't even access the database.

Comment: You can create database diagrams using Management Studio, provided you have appropriate permissions. [http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1816/getting-started-with-sql-server-database-diagrams/](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1816/getting-started-with-sql-server-database-diagrams/)

Comment: I don't have the appropriate permissions

Comment: sorry, by tool I mean a program that makes the diagram for you. Of course you need a tool to display the data in the database

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you a list of foreign keys in a SQL Server 2008 database. This query requires the `VIEW DEFINITION` permission on your database.

```
SELECT 
     OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id)                      AS Parent_Table
    ,OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)                          AS Child_Table
    ,COL_NAME(referenced_object_id,referenced_column_id)    AS Parent_Column
    ,COL_NAME(parent_object_id,parent_column_id)            AS Child_Column
    ,OBJECT_NAME(constraint_object_id)                      AS FK_Name
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns
ORDER BY Parent_Table, Child_Table
```